# Как добавлять свои элементы в уведомление Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, windows-10

Нужно добавить элемент TreeView в уведомление Windows. Язык программирования: C#(wpf). Например, вот так выглядит уведомление с кнопками:

[image: Windows notification with buttons]

Подскажите, с помощью какой функции Winapi это можно сделать или можно обойтись без Winapi? Вообще возможно ли добавить TreeView в такое уведомление?

Comment: Как вы выводите это уведомление? Покажите код.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight с помощью _NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip()_, но так можно только простые текстовые уведомления посылать, а мне надо с treeview. Так что думаю, тут нужно будет задействовать winapi

Comment: Вы можете просто создать окно без рамки (WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize") и установить его координыты в правый нижний угол экрана. Специальной функциональности для отображения сложных уведомлений в WinAPI нет (возможно, есть сторонние библиотеки для этого).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight да, но мне хочется узнать именно про такие уведомления

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `UWP` делается это с помощью [`ToastNotification`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b876a/toast-notification-in-windows-10-uwp).

В `WPF` можно сделать все вручную (создавать окно с `WindowsStyle="None"`), или использовать Win10 API ([пример](http://michaelcrump.net/pop-toast-notification-in-wpf)).

Comment: То есть TreeView нельзя запихать в уведомление?

Comment: @Александр, вот что win10 api позволяет закинуть: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts 
Вывод: вам придется делать свое `toastnotification`

Comment: @Александр, интерактивный (с разворачиванием/сворачиванием структуры) вряд ли. Либо переделывать в тексторый формат с псевдографикой, либо рендерить в картинку, которую прикреплять к уведомлению.