# Не появляется notifyicon при вызове

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть пустая форма `Form1` и присоедененная к ней notifyicon1. В скрипте `Form1.cs` в функции `public Form1_Load` написано следующее:

```
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
// задаем текст подсказки
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Нажмите, чтобы отобразить окно";
// устанавливаем зголовк
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Подсказка";
// отображаем подсказку 12 секунд
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(12);
```

Но при тестировании ничего не появляется. Мне нужно чтобы появлялось уведомление.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу. Тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой. Прошерстил множество сайтов, но так и не нашёл решения.

Comment: @Александр, у меня есть догадки, что notifyicon работаю с Windows 8.1 и ниже т.к. в Windows 10 такого больше нет...

Comment: В том то и дело, что у меня получалось это сделать на Windows 10. Я вопрос задавал ещё по этому поводу (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792381/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-windows-10). Однако, через некоторое время опять пробовал это сделать, но уже не получалось.

Comment: Вы не забыли иконку назначить `notifyIcon1.Icon = ...;` и сделать `notifyIcon1.Visible = true;`? Проверил сейчас - всё работает на Десятке.